# How can I get miniatures with specific features?

Tags: miniatures

Is there somewhere you can get minis corresponding to the class, race and sex of adventurers, be it singles or a giant collection of minis?

For example: I might be looking for a male elf druid and a female half-orc fighter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the very near future, probably this year, expect [Hero Forge's customizable 3d printed tabletop miniatures](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/heroforge/customizable-3d-printed-tabletop-miniatures) to be funded and providing truly customizable features to the market.

For now, you can probably find the coarser attributes as described in the many answers here. However, beyond gender, race ("specie"), and class you'll probably have to "settle" if say you want a female elf ranger with long hair and a quarterstaff, but it's only available with the hoodie, bow and cape. It happens.

Also consider hack kits that let advanced miniature modelers replace (or add) weapons, gear and other features. [Fenryll](http://fenryll.com/en/) provides some of these options; see any of their 3-stage sets and accessory kits.

Answer (score 8):

If you are ordering online, several of the miniature houses have mini finders. For instance, [Reaper Miniature's Figure Finder](http://www.reapermini.com/FigureFinder).

These will let you find the mini you want based on race, sex, weapons, class etc.

Answer (score 5):

There are several websites and stores that sell single miniatures and most of them also have a handy race, class, type search bar. I personally ordered an extra set of miniatures and the two stores that I used are:

[Troll & Toad](http://www.trollandtoad.com)

[Miniature Market](http://www.miniaturemarket.com)

That said, ordering single miniatures is quite costly and you might be better off going to local gaming conventions and/or larger gaming stores if there are any near by.

Answer (score 1):

Many gaming stores sell miniatures individually, and it gives a good opportunity to purchase according to your specific needs and desires.  However, many miniatures are tied to wargame systems that cause them to have value that varies greatly and has little correlation to their aesthetic appearance - you might find a druid-looking guy for 99 cents, while the female half-orc could be $20.  Your best option would be to view the miniature sets online and carefully browse the prices to see which ones fit your needs at reasonable rates.