# Where can I get miniatures of The Four Horsemen of Apocalyse?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, game-recommendation, miniatures

I have looked a lot online but I am reaching the end of my search. I was wondering if anyone knows where I can buy miniatures of the Four Horsemen of the Apocalypse — ideally resembling the Pathfinder description, but I will take anything that is close.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please check out the [tour] and the [help]. I've done some editing to try to make this question fit the site a bit better, feel free to revert or edit if it no longer says what you want it to.

Comment: This feels like a question that can end too easily in a list - or even worse, one who's answer is highly localized to the timeframe when the answer came from...

Comment: @Tritium21 That I've given the question a massage doesn't mean I've put a Mod Stamp of Approval on it, so do vote your conscience!

Comment: I VTCed as Primarily Opinion Based as (baring someone coming along and posting a link to a product I am almost sure does not exist) it is purely subjective if a mini is a pathfinder horseman.  this is amongst many reasons this is not a great question for this site.

Comment: Relevant: [How can I get miniatures with specific features?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/33524/1204)

Comment: I don't really see how this is going to be a question with good answers. I could link you to the games workshop site and tell you to convert something out of those kits, but is that better than somebody who links you to a model from a different company which is cheaper, but looks terrible?

Answer (score -2):

Games Workshop has a line of Lord of the Rings miniatures, among which there are nine for mounted Nazgul. Any of them would make servicable horsemen, though I would recommend, "Khamul the Easterling" for the Horseman of War, and, "The Tainted" for the Horseman of Pestilence. They are a bit pricey as the models come in pairs, one mounted and one on foot.

[Mordor - Heroes](http://www.games-workshop.com/en-US/The-Hobbit?N=102353%204294967052%204294966788&Nu=product.repositoryId&qty=12&sorting=phl&view=table&categoryId=cat410002-flat)

That link should provide you with all of them, but if for some reason it doesn't work you can find them using the categories, "Mordor" and, "Heroes." They do not show up under, "Cavalry."

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please read the [tour] and the [help] to get an introduction. More importantly, though, please read the banner under the question: "All responses must cite actual experience or reference others' experiences!" Your answer doesn't do this, so it will probably be downvoted and possibly be deleted.

Comment: If I had said I used, "The Tainted" to represent Pestilence in one of my games, would my reply have been acceptable? I'm not sure of the value of my link to Hinchy, but its value is certainly not dependent on whether I've personally used the miniature or not.

Comment: How closely do these suggested miniatures match the descriptions of the Golarion Four Horsemen? Are there any details that conflict with their descriptions, such that someone might want to remove parts of the model before painting? (This sort of information is likely to be something someone who has used these for this purpose could provide, but if you can provide it, great.)

Answer (score -2):

try this link - these figures looks pretty impressive.
http://www.keepwargaming.co.uk/reaper-fantasy-25mm28mm--four-horsemen-of-the-apocalypse-15-p.asp