# High Quality wizard miniatures? (for Ars Magica)

Tags: wizard, miniatures, ars-magica-5, ars-magica

I would like to buy dozens of different wizard miniatures, to use them in Ars Magica (I know they are not necessary, but I would like to use them any way, to illustrate positioning of the party and enemies, etc.)

I think I would find tons of them easily on the internet, but I actually had a hard time doing so.

Eventually I found a decent ammount of them in [Reaper Miniatures](http://www.reapermini.com/Miniatures/young%20wizard), but as you can check, the quality is not amazing (not bad though...)

Any other wizard miniatures of better quality that you could know?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get miniatures with specific features?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/33524/how-can-i-get-miniatures-with-specific-features)

Comment: @doppelgreener Thank you! The selected answer to that question is... It's incredible that something like that exists... :D

Comment: Actually, I think the quality of Reaper Minis is quite high.